# What does "the means" mean here?

Tags: meaning, phrases

To reach an exceptionally high standard in any area very able children need THE MEANS to learn

Comment: Do any definitions in the dictionary seem to fit?

Comment: "Means" in this sense is a noun, meaning "necessary resources".

Comment: _Means_ is a tough one. The verb has so many ... um ... meanings. And this is a noun, in a construction: _the means to learn_, means _the stuff you need in order to learn_.

Comment: "The means" to do something are the resources needed to do it. They are all the resources and can include physical supplies, finance, time, personal and emotional support and even the transport to the school or other venue.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to ask what are the specific actions, objects and systems needed for very able children to learn? If so the question is off topic; it must be asked on some other site, a pedagogy site for instance, or some other similar site.